# Jhipster auditing,wrong modified by name

Tags: jhipster, audit

I want to save 10k users from active directory and i am using auditing but I have a bug.
The column modified_by does not work well.
The error is

```
2016-04-04 14:49:27,353 DEBUG [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] StateServiceImpl: Request to save userAD, 77879
2016-04-04 14:49:27,354 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-6] StateServiceImpl: Request to save userAD, 96459
```

As you can randomly it is using threads. When it is using ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-X in the modified_by column fill in with the name "system" and when it is called from http-nio-80-exec-X it filled by the name of the user who is logged in.

thanx

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your `.yo-rc.json` file and JHipster version.
Indicate also how you load you 10k users: through REST API or something else?
Did you write/modify this code or is it the code generated by JHipster unmodified?

`SecurityContextHolder` probably uses a `ThreadLocal` variable to store current user and then if you start a thread you do not get this context copied to the execution thread which results in getting default user: `system`

Comment: i am using the latest version of jhipster (3.0.0) with some fixes like beanfactory....

Comment: List<UserAD> users = adService.findAll();      users.parallelStream().forEach(uAd -> {       ............       ptolUser.setUserAd(uAd);       ........... }

Comment: https://github.com/akeske/test2/blob/testing/com/ppc/ptol2/web/rest/AccountResource.java

in line 294+ i put my functionallity inside this request for testing only....

Comment: i tried another way to loop. i used "for (UserAD uAd : users) {" instead of  "parallelStream().forEach(uAd -> {". With this change all the new rows inside the db have my name as created_by. why is happening this?